# Syntax error when using ScalarDB with DynamoDB reserved words as column names

Tags: scalardb

I want to use ScalarDB with a schema called user created in DynamoDB.

As an example, the user schema is defined as follows

```
{
  "sample_db.user": {
    "transaction": true,
    "partition-key": [
      "user_id".
    ],
    "clustering-key": [],
    "columns": {
      "user_id": "TEXT",
      "user_name": "TEXT",
      "status": "TEXT"
    },
    "ru": 5000,
    "compaction-strategy": "LCS",
    "secondary-index": [
      "status": "TEXT"
    ]
  }
}
```

I was able to create this user schema in DynamoDB.
However, when I perform CRUD processing on this schema using the ScalarDB functionality, DynamoDB returns a syntax violation error because the 'status' is a reserved word.

DynamoDB's reserved words are summarized here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

In this case, I would like to know if engineers using ScalarDB should define their schema with this issue in mind.
I'd be happy if future improvements would make it possible to use database-specific reserved words in column names and still use the ScalarDB functionality.

Comment: Could you paste a snippet of you code and the error messages? Scalar DB should work on a table that has columns with reserved keywords by using aliases internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed in the following PR:
https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/pull/264

And this fix will be in the next releases: Scalar DB 3.2.0, 3.1.1 and 3.0.2.